# How to detect an object on my screen and perform a task

Tags: python

I want to automate a simple task of clicking a certain button on a windows program every X seconds until it turns a specific color.

That is, there is a program on my screen with the blue color button, I want to use a python script to click this button until it turns green.

Is there a way to do this? use python to recognize a certain object or color on mine and click on it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the platform, there are various methods of capturing the screen and sending keyboard / mouse events. I've used [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in the past, it wraps the APIs of most popular platforms, so it will likely work out-of-the-box.

```py
import pyautogui

# Regular PIL / PILLOW image
screen_img = pyautogui.screenshot()

color = screen_img.getpixel((100, 100))

if color == (255, 0, 0):
    pyautogui.click(100, 200)
```